# Apache Beam Python SDK does not support Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, apache-beam

I am using Python 3.10.11, and my requirements.txt file looks like this:

```
apache-beam==2.46.0
cachetools==4.2.4
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
cloudpickle==2.2.1
crcmod==1.7
dill==0.3.1.1
docopt==0.6.2
fastavro==1.7.3
fasteners==0.18
google-api-core==1.34.0
google-apitools==0.5.31
google-auth==2.17.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-cloud-bigquery==3.3.3
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.16.0
google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.3
google-cloud-core==1.7.3
google-cloud-datastore==1.15.5
google-cloud-dlp==3.9.0
google-cloud-firestore==2.0.0
google-cloud-language==1.3.2
google-cloud-pubsub==2.13.7
google-cloud-pubsublite==1.8.1
google-cloud-recommendations-ai==0.7.1
google-cloud-spanner==3.22.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.3
google-cloud-vision==3.1.2
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.4
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.4
grpcio==1.54.0
grpcio-status==1.48.2
hdfs==2.7.0
httplib2==0.21.0
idna==3.4
numpy==1.24.3
oauth2client==4.1.3
objsize==0.6.1
orjson==3.8.11
overrides==6.5.0
packaging==21.3
proto-plus==1.22.2
protobuf==3.19.4
pyarrow==9.0.0
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pydot==1.4.2
pymongo==3.13.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
regex==2023.3.23
requests==2.29.0
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.15
zstandard==0.21.0
```

I have created a simple pipeline in Apache Beam to export Google Cloud Firestore collections to various files:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions
from google.cloud import firestore
from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import DatetimeWithNanoseconds
import json
import argparse
from my_module import get_collections #gets list of FS collections as string

class FirestoreToGcs(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        client = firestore.Client()
        docs = client.collection(element).get()
        for doc in docs:
            doc_dict = doc.to_dict()
            for key in doc_dict:
             if isinstance(doc_dict[key], DatetimeWithNanoseconds):
              doc_dict[key] = doc_dict[key].isoformat()
            yield json.dumps(doc_dict)


def run(argv=None):
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument(
        "--output-bucket",
        dest="output_bucket",
        required=True,
        help="GCS bucket to write output files to",
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = arg_parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        collections = get_collections()
        for collection in collections:
            (p
             | f"Read_{collection}" >> beam.Create([collection])
             | f"MapDocuments_{collection}" >> beam.ParDo(FirestoreToGcs())
             | f"WriteToGcs_{collection}" >> beam.io.WriteToText(f"{known_args.output_bucket}/{collection}.jsonl")
             )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

However, I am getting the following error while running my pipeline:

```
fs_beam_exporter.py", line 13, in process NameError: name 'firestore' is not defined [while running 'MapDocuments_doc-ptransform-46']
```

I have found questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484490/apache-beam-dataflow-pub-sub-side-input-with-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286517/importing-google-firestore-python-client-in-apache-beam) indicating there are indeed dependency conflicts with Apache Beam and other GCP libraries. Have these conflicts been resolved?

Comment: The `pip install` command finished correctly ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yes, though it has given warnings that there are dependency conflicts.

Comment: Please share with us the exact requirements.txt file.

Comment: @MazlumTosun I've shown the result of `pip freeze` above. That should be sufficient for the requirements.txt

Comment: Sorry but I wanted to have the exact packages you added in your requirement.txt file please, not the result by pip feeze. I am going to try to reproduce this issue on my side.

Comment: @MazlumTosun Alright, I have included the appropriate requirements.txt file

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is not due to a package conflict because, you have your error at runtime and you could have installed your package with `pip`.

In my opinion your issue is due to a package `import` not visible inside workers.

You added your import at the top of your `main` file, and sometimes in this case, the imported packages are not visible inside workers.

To solve your issue, I propose to import the package inside the `process` method of the `DoFn` class :

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions
from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import DatetimeWithNanoseconds
import json
import argparse
from my_module import get_collections #gets list of FS collections as string

class FirestoreToGcs(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        from google.cloud import firestore

        client = firestore.Client()
        docs = client.collection(element).get()
        for doc in docs:
            doc_dict = doc.to_dict()
            for key in doc_dict:
             if isinstance(doc_dict[key], DatetimeWithNanoseconds):
              doc_dict[key] = doc_dict[key].isoformat()
            yield json.dumps(doc_dict)


def run(argv=None):
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument(
        "--output-bucket",
        dest="output_bucket",
        required=True,
        help="GCS bucket to write output files to",
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = arg_parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        collections = get_collections()
        for collection in collections:
            (p
             | f"Read_{collection}" >> beam.Create([collection])
             | f"MapDocuments_{collection}" >> beam.ParDo(FirestoreToGcs())
             | f"WriteToGcs_{collection}" >> beam.io.WriteToText(f"{known_args.output_bucket}/{collection}.jsonl")
             )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

In this case, the package will necessarily be visible in the workers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the same error appeared. If you have any other ideas let me know.